# String concatenation inside macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

To print several fields of a struct, I have to say the following line repeatedly:

```
cout << "field1=" << ptr->get_field1()
```

So I defined the following macro, and use it like this:

```
#define FIELD(s, id) << s"=" << ptr->get_##id()

FIELD("field1", field1);
FIELD("field2", field2);
```

This works. But I have to mention the same name twice in the macro - once as a string, another time as a variable. Is there a better way to do it?

(The title of this question does not exactly indicate the question, but I could not think of a more appropriate short combination of words. Sorry about that!)

Comment: You can eliminate `s` argument and use `id` directly, using concatenation again (`##`).

Comment: You mean like: ... << "##id=" << ptr->get_##id() ? That did not work, it is printing: ##id=<whatever value>

Comment: I was a bit wrong, see the answers, I think they show what you need :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [stringify](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) `id`:

```
#define FIELD(id) << #id "=" << ptr->get_##id()

FIELD(field1);   // << "field1" "=" << ptr->get_field1()
FIELD(field2);   // << "field2" "=" << ptr->get_field2()
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2190451f12e05185)

For `FIELD(field1)`, it partly results in this expression:

```
"field1" "="
```

which is two literal strings put side-by-side. These two are then concatenated, resulting in a string equivalent to `"field1="`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
#define FIELD(id) << #id "=" << ptr->get_##id()
```

The # operator in a macro means "make this into a string".

Answer (score 0):

'#' does the trick:

```
#define FIELD(s) << #s"=" << ptr->get_##s()
```

or even:

```
#define FIELD(i)  << "field"#i"=" << ptr->get_field##i()
```